# Does setting of width and height only work in jquery if the element is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does setting of width and height only work in jquery if the element is visible?
Unless I do show - nothing gets resized, however this is causing flickering.
Is there a way to make it work even when the element I want to resize or its container is not visible?

Comment: You ndded to show us how youre trying to change height/width with some example code.... a jsfiddle would be ideal :-)

Comment: Not at all, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/L25Xg/).

Comment: I don't at all get what your problem is, everything looks they way it should too me. Are your looking for animations?

Comment: Also, could you include your browser and steps to show the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting the height/width sets attributes directly no matter what the old value was, it doesn't matter if it's visible or not.
Getting the height and width might be a different story.

How do you know it doesn't get resized if it's hidden? How are you hiding the elements?

---

I've tried resizing a div when having `visibility:hidden;` on it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/RUThh/

And here with `display:none;`: http://jsfiddle.net/PAvzn/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. What I did to fix it was use jQuery to temporarily give it a position:absolute, then I "showed" it at -9999px which triggered the browser rendering the element and thus giving it dimensions, read those dimensions, then put it back and made it invisible again.